# Quadratic equation solver nan square root positive number

Tags: java, quadratic

I was coding a very simple quadratic eqation solver but the answer kept coming up nan even when the square root was positive (the example I was using was 1x^2+5x+6 where b^2=25 and 4*a*c= 24) but it was still coming up nan. Please help.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;
public class HelloWorld {
      public static void main (String[] args){
      System.out.println ("type quadratic equation please use format ax^2+/-bx+/-c");
Scanner userInput=new Scanner(System.in);
String userEquation=userInput.next();
char a=(userEquation.charAt(0));
char b=(userEquation.charAt(5));
char c=(userEquation.charAt(8));
System.out.println(a);
 System.out.println(b);
  System.out.println(c);
  double p1=4*a*c;
  double p2=2*a;
  double p3=-b;
  double p4=b*b;
  double p5=p4-p1;
  double p6=Math.sqrt(p5);
  double pa7=-b+p6;
  double pb7=-b-p6;
  double pa8=pa7/2*a;
  double pb8=pb7/2*a;
  System.out.println("x1= "+pa8+ " x2="+pb8);
}
}
```

Comment: It would be better to ask the user for 3 inputs rather than relying on him entering the correct equation format but this has nothing to do with your issue ;)

Comment: Just print your temporary variables and you'll see the problem. Hint : `char` != `int` or `double`.

Comment: Save yourself a lot of time and get familiar with using a debugger. Virtually any IDE has one and they are very easy to use. A debugger allows you to step through the program line by line and inspect the values of all variables. You'd then notice immediately that `a` in your program is `49` instead of `1`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never parse your `char` to a `double` to do math.

Try this:

```
double a=Double.parseDouble(userEquation.charAt(0)+"");
double b=Double.parseDouble(userEquation.charAt(5)+"");
double c=Double.parseDouble(userEquation.charAt(8)+"");
```

This changes your variable type to `double` so you can continue on with your code and do math.

I agree with @Gaël's comment. Add a print statement for your other variables (`p1`, `p2`, etc.) and notice the difference when you leave the variables `a`, `b`, and `c` as type `char` or type `double`.

Comment: Indeed, the character `'0'` has a value of `48` so if you want to do math, first convert `char` to `int` or `double`.

Comment: Thanks for further input @Gaël.